# MVC3 MapRoute, parameter with slashes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, maproute

How would i create a MapRoute that accepts slashes without considering it a new parameter?
If the url is

```
http://localhost/root/p1/default.aspx
```

I want one parameter to pick up everything after localhost (root/p1/default.aspx). Normally it would take three parameters for this because there are two slashes, and maproute separates the parameters by slash.
So if the route looks something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "URLMapRoute",
   "{path}",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", path = "default.aspx" }
);
```

then {path} picks up everything, even though the url contains slashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a catchall route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "URLMapRoute",
    "{*path}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", path = "default.aspx" }
);
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index(string path)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Any help on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932519/mvc-how-to-manage-slahses-in-route-parameters/